# Can I pass a HashSet<SomeEnumeration> as HashSet<byte>?

Tags: c#, enums, hashset

I have a function written that takes a `HashSet<byte>` parameter. I would like to pass a `HashSet<SomeEnumeration>` where `SomeEnumeration` has underlying type `byte`. Is there a simple way to do this?

```
public enum SomeEnumeration : byte
{
    ZERO = 0,
    ONE,
    TWO,
    THREE
}

public void someFunc( HashSet<byte> aSet )
{
    ...
}

static void Main()
{
    HashSet<SomeEnumeration> mySet = new HashSet<SomeEnumeration>();

    ...
    someFunc(mySet);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use `Cast` extension method to do it:

```
someFunc(new HashSet<byte>(mySet.Cast<byte>()));
```

Comment: This will only work if the method parameter is typed as `IEnumerable<byte>`. If the method actually requires that you pass a `HashSet<byte>`, then you would have to make a copy of the set by doing `new HashSet<byte>(set.Cast<byte>())`.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I just changed the function parameter to be `IEnumerable<byte>` instead of `HashSet<byte>`.